# Server-sent data into a table

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, json

I have a simple Server-sent event setup I'm trying to make display as a table. Currently I have the SSE php page pulling the data out of the MySQL table and sending the data over as a Json array to the live page. How would I be able to take the Json array and put that into a html table with out sending the array back as a post and causing the page to "refresh"?

Here is my current code

SSE.php

```
//get MySQL data
$new_data = getVar();
//Create Array
$data_array = array();
//add data to array
while($row = $new_data->fetch_assoc()){
    $data_array[] = $row;
    $out = array_values($data_array);
    $new_out = json_encode($out);
}
//echo the array to html page
echo "data: $new_out \n\n }'";
```

Index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //check for browser support
 if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {
 //create an object, passing it the name and location of the server side script
var eSource = new EventSource("send_sse.php");
//detect message receipt
eSource.onmessage = function(event) {
    //write the received data to the page
    //document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML = event.data;
};
```

Where serverData is the div where the array is currently being shown

I have tried to echo data: multiple times or echo the html markup back but I couldn't make it work with out a php runtime error

thanks

Comment: What does the actual returned json look like? Probably your php is returning invalid json, you could likely replace all the above php with `echo json_encode(getVar()->fetch_all());`

Comment: @Steve this is currently the data in the database `data:[{"ID":"1","Name":"Ryan","City":"Lake Mary"},``{"ID":"3","Name":"test","City":"test"},{"ID":"4","Name":"asdad","City":"asd"},{"ID":"5","Name":"test","City":"test"},{"ID":"6","Name":"asdad","City":"asd"},{"ID":"7","Name":"ZXX","City":"ZX"},{"ID":"8","Name":"ZXX","City":"ZX"},{"ID":"9","Name":"dsgs","City":"asdss"}] 

 }'`

Comment: Also the main thing with SSE events is all echos must start as a string with `"data: "`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make an AJAX request to the PHP script. This will allow the data from the database table to populate your page without refreshing. Check out [this W3Schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp).

You can simplify the user defined JavaScript by using [jQuery's AJAX functions](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp) (though you would have to load jQuery onto your page as well).